# Appending similar strings to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am running into a small issue when appending a string into a file. So basically, I am appending books that does not exist in the file using this:

```
def writeBooks2File(booklist_dir):
    BOOKS = ['Human Philosophy', 'Human Philosophy book']
    for val in BOOKS:
        if val not in open(booklist_dir, "r").read():
            f = open(booklist_dir, "a")
            f.write(val + "\n")
            f.close()
```

My file contains the following:

```
Human Philosophy
Human Philosophy book
```

Lets say I remove `Human Philosophy`, the file contains `Human Philosophy book` only. Running `writeBooks2File(booklist_dir)` again does not return this output:

```
Human Philosophy
Human Philosophy book
```

But return this instead:

```
Human Philosophy book
```

What do I need to do to make add `Human Philosophy` into the file with both values being similar to one another.

Comment: using `read` you get the entire file as one string. Use `readlines` instead to get a list of the titles in your file, so you can search for the exact string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
>>> 'Human Philosophy' in 'Human Philosophy book\n'
True
```

Therefore you can do this:

```
>>> ('Human Philosophy'+'\n') in 'Human Philosophy book\n'
False
```

I rewrote your script... This should give you better using

```
def writeBooks2File(booklist_dir,books):
    f = open(booklist_dir, "a")
    for val in books:
        if val+'\n' not in open(booklist_dir, "r").read():

            f.write(val + "\n")
    f.close()

def removebooks(booklist_dir,books):
    with open(booklist_dir, "r") as File:
        all_books = File.read()
    for book in books:
        new = all_books.replace(book+'\n','')
    with open(booklist_dir, "w") as File:
        File.write(new)
books = ['Human Philosophy book','Human Philosophy']        
writeBooks2File('test.txt',books)

remove_books = ['Human Philosophy'] 
removebooks('test.txt',remove_books)
```

With this, you can do what you were not able to do. Append the file with 'Human Philosophy' even if there is 'Human Philosophy book'

Comment: Just a note: You're opening the file twice, but closing it just once; otherwise it looks good enough for me.